# Error to starting QJackCTL

Tags: server, sound, connection, jack

i am using Ubuntu-Studio (20.04) i installed it a few days ago on a CX216 notebook, and it gives me the following error when trying to start QjackCTL:
PS: I had previously tried installing it on a netbook of "Conectar igualdad" and it started well.

Error
D-BUS: Jack server cannot start

Jack server cannot be contacted as a client.
-The global operation failed
-The server cannot connect.
Please check the message window for more information.

Detail:

```
12:48:55.304 Reiniciar estadísticas.
12:48:55.337 Cambios en las conexiones ALSA.
12:48:55.366 D-BUS: Disponible (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
12:48:55.670 Cambió el gráfico de conexiones ALSA.
12:48:59.306 D-BUS: El servidor JACK no puede iniciarse. Disculpa
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Fri Jul 3 12:48:58 2020: Starting jack server...
Fri Jul 3 12:48:58 2020: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Fri Jul 3 12:48:58 2020: self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: Acquired audio card Audio0
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: creating alsa driver ...
hw:0|hw:0|1024|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for playback. Falling back to capture-only mode
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: Released audio card Audio0
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Fri Jul 3 12:48:59 2020: ERROR: Failed to open server
Fri Jul 3 12:49:00 2020: Saving settings to
"/home/shirubius/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 883, resource id: 12667603, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
12:49:03.946 No puede conectarse al servidor JACK como cliente. - La operación global falló. - No puede conectarse al servidor. Por favor revise la ventana de mensajes para mas información.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No existe el archivo o el directorio
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 1064,resource id: 12668286, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try launching `qjackctl` after disabling pulseaudio using this command:

```bsh
pasuspender qjackctl
```

If this fails, this command returns the process using sound device:
`sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`
If pulseaudio is the locking process: disable pulseaudio autospawn then kill it:
`echo autospawn=no > ~/.config/pulse/client.conf`
`killall pulseaudio`

When finished with jackd, revert to autospawned pulseaudio :
`echo autospawn=yes > ~/.config/pulse/client.conf`
start pulseaudio:
`pulseaudio`

Comment: I tried this and still get error -----------ERROR: Cannot lock down 82280346 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
ERROR: control open "hw:USB" (No such device)
Wed Jul  8 09:12:08 2020: Acquired audio card Audio2
hw:PCH|hw:USB|128|2|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
ERROR: 
ATTENTION: The playback device "hw:PCH" is already in use. Please stop the application using it and run JACK again
ERROR: control open "hw:USB" (No such device)

Comment: Added fuser test in answer

Comment: USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND  
/dev/snd/controlC0:  joeuser   1807 F.... pulseaudio  
/dev/snd/controlC2:  joeuser   1807 F.... pulseaudio

Comment: so pulseaudio is blocking audio, try the commands to disable pulseaudio ( added commands to reactivate it)

Comment: This is transmogrifying. I will create another question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257990/jack-audio-connection-kit-frozen