# JACK Audio Connection Kit / VMPK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I do this:

```
$ echo autospawn=no > ~/.config/pulse/client.conf  
$ killall pulseaudio  
pulseaudio: no process found  
$ pasuspender qjackctl  
Connection failure: Connection refused  
pa_context_connect() failed: Invalid argument  
$ qjackctl  
^Z  
[1]+  Stopped                 qjackctl  
$ vmpk &  
[2] 2955
```

At this point I see:

[image: screenshot]
Originally, the keyboard worked but with no sound. Now the keyboard doesn't work.

Also, I have installed FluidSynth
What should the connections be?

--- more info ---

Upon starting the computer, I open Audacity and play a wav file and no sound. In fact, there is no audio whatsoever, e.g. Youtube in a browser is silent.

I look at Settings > Sound, nothing there:

[image: settings]

Then I do this:

```
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  mickeydog   2923 F.... audacity
/dev/snd/seq:        mickeydog   2923 F.... audacity
```

Then I do the following. Despite the errors, Youtube audio works after this, though not Audacity:

```
$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-AKAI_MPKmini2_0001-01" card_name="alsa_card.usb-AKAI_MPKmini2_0001-01" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- error "pulseaudio no process found" means pulseaudio is not running so the "killall pulseaudio" command  is not needed (and report an error)
- as pulseaudio not running, use `qjackctl` command ( or its  menu icon)   instead of `pasuspender qjackctl`
- for midi and jack, it don't know but look in qjackctl settings for midi driver selection.

Comment: Added to question

Comment: midi connection seems ok (but i don't use midi) . If no audio , test jack setup by playing sound with Ardour or Audacity (configured to use  jack audio instead pulseaudio) , or vlc (configured to use jack audio , need installing vlc-plugin-jack   first)

Comment: Added more info to question

Comment: For the test, audacity must be set to use jack audio: it is not , from the fuser result (it use direct Alsa .). Search youtube video that explain  jack audio,  as it is confusing espaecially the interaction with pulseaudio .  Anyway use alsamixer (or gnome-alsamixer) to set volume when pulseaudio is stopped.